# Advice on creating a screensaver updatable via a CMS

Tags: java, python

I've been asked to provide someone with a screensaver which contains some content pulled from a mysql database. Having never developed a screensaver before, I'm wondering how best to go about this. The screensaver will be used in an office of around 20 machines running Windows - I was originally going to use Flash to develop the screensaver, then export it to .scr format, however the need for dynamic content is making me wonder if i can do this better with python or java? Does anyone have experience or advice for this type of thing? Many thanks

Comment: Flash can talk HTTP, so that should work, unless there are limits in the export to scr format.

Answer (score 0):

[PyScreensaver](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/py430/python/index.html) (plus maybe some TurboGears or Django for managing the database on the server side, if you don't have anything for that, yet)